# How can I run PowerPC programs in OS X Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, compatibility, powerpc

I need to run PowerPC-only programs roughly weekly. They're on a CD rather than the HD, so they escaped my pre-flight upgrade checks. As Rosetta was killed in the last upgrade
it's problematic to run those programs in OS X Lion.

My options are as follows:

1. Downgrade to Snow Leopard;
2. Set up Snow Leopard on a bootcamped partiton;
3. Virtualise Snow Leopard under some kind of VM (VirtualBox, Parallels or Fusion).

I don't particularly want to do 1 or 2 unless I have to.  I still want the benefit of Lion if I can — and rebooting to do a small printing job seems excessive, so it seems virtualisation is the best option.

Are there any other alternative methods I've missed?
Is here a better product for running one Apple OS under another (simplest – I'm willing to pay if necessary)?

Comment: 3. (with SL virtual machine, not Lion) is against Apple's license agreement and considered off-topic on this site. I think your list is pretty complete.

Comment: You can virtualise the server version legally?

Comment: SL Server, true.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out the program was a wrapper for a pdf so it didn't need anything too fancy to fix it.
I found that out after I'd tried to virtualise Snow Leopard, which didn't work.
Ended up using VirtualBox to run program in Windows XP.